# Converting string to control

Tags: c#, beginner, strings, winforms

I have an up-down numeric control on my form (`attEdgeUpDown`), which has value 0-8. I have eight checkboxes (`attEdgeBox1` to `attEdgeBox8`). I want to display as many boxes as the numeric control shows.

Can this be done more efficiently?

```
private void attEdgeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int edgeValue = Convert.ToInt32(attEdgeUpDown.Value);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
    string checkboxName = "attEdgeBox" + Convert.ToString(i);
    Control[] checkboxControl = this.Controls.Find(checkboxName, true);
        if (i <= edgeValue)
            {
                (checkboxControl[0] as CheckBox).Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                (checkboxControl[0] as CheckBox).Visible = false;
                (checkboxControl[0] as CheckBox).Checked = false;
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: @BCdotWEB is right.. That part of your question is off topic. I suggest reading [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to review appropriate topics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you're working with an ancient version of .NET, `Convert.ToString(i);` is superfluous. You should be able to just do `"attEdgeBox" + i;`.

---

If you're certain that those checkboxes exist, you can do `var checkBox = this.Controls.Find(checkboxName, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;` and then work with `checkBox` instead of doing `(checkboxControl[0] as CheckBox)` repeatedly.

---

Note that `CheckBox` is a compound name, so `checkboxName` as a variable name is incorrect; it should be `checkBoxName`.

---

What type is `attEdgeUpDown`, and why does it return a value that isn't an `int`? Seems odd to me that a control that returns a value from 1 to 8 would return this in a non-numeric format.

Comment: `attEdgeUpDown` is a `NumericUpDown` control. When I first ran the code I had trouble with it since it would return a `decimal` and ran into trouble comparing it to `int`. I've tried it again just now and it works fine without the conversion. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the string indexer of the ControlCollection instead of its method Find (provided the searched control is a direct child) aka use `var checkBox = (CheckBox) Controls[checkBoxName];` ? I also use a simple cast because if it's not a CheckBox it **is** an error and someone has to be notified (instead of silently hiding the problem)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yeah, I didn't consider that. Makes it indeed a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer of *BCdotWEB*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134532/22020) provides several good points on improvement. Here's my addition to this.

What struck me is the loop. You iterate *all* the checkboxes *every* time the value of the numeric up/down changes. In this scenario, when you only have 8 of them, this is not a big matter. But the code can be simplified though.

The solution to avoid the loop is to keep track of the previous value of the numeric up/down and determine if the new value is higher or lower. Based on this, you select the correct checkbox and you only have to set this one checkbox visible/checked or not.

The code will make this much clearer, I'll provide comment in the code to explain. (I assumed that all checkboxes are set to `Visible = false` and the numeric up/down has a default value of 0).

```
//private field to keep track of the previous value
private decimal _previousValue;

private void attEdgeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get new value
    var edgeValue = attEdgeUpDown.Value;

    //check if the new value is higher or lower
    var isHigher = edgeValue > _previousValue;

    //if the new value is higher than before, use that value
    //if the new value is lower, take the value + 1
    var checkboxName = "attEdgeBox" + (isHigher ? edgeValue : edgeValue + 1);
    var checkboxControl = Controls.Find(checkboxName, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;

    //set the visibility
    checkboxControl.Visible = isHigher;

    //if the new value is lower, uncheck the checkbox
    if (!isHigher)
        checkboxControl.Checked = false;

    //store the current value in the `_previousValue` field
    _previousValue = edgeValue;
}
```

So for example, you have 0 as current value and you go up 1. This means that `isHigher` will be `true` and we will use the value of `edgeValue`, which is 1. We will take `attEdgeBox1` and set it visible, we don't check/uncheck it. At last we store the value `1` in the `_previousValue` field.

A reverse example. We have a current value of 7 and we go down 1. `isHigher` will be `false` and we will use the value of `edgeValue + 1`. This means we will take `attEdgeBox7` and set it invisible, we also uncheck it. At last, store the value 6 in `_previousValue`.

**Edit:**

Following code allows manual input of a value in the numeric up/down. Since this means that the difference between the new value and the previous value can be more than 1, you cannot evade using a loop. Following code minimizes the loop, meaning you don't have to iterate over *all* checkboxes.

```
private void attEdgeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var edgeValue = attEdgeUpDown.Value;
    var isHigher = edgeValue > _previousValue;
    var min = isHigher ? _previousValue : edgeValue;
    var max = isHigher ? edgeValue : _previousValue;

    while (min++ < max)
    {
        var checkboxName = "attEdgeBox" + min;
        var checkboxControl = Controls.Find(checkboxName, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;

        checkboxControl.Visible = isHigher;
        if (!isHigher)
            checkboxControl.Checked = false;
    }
    _previousValue = edgeValue;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but would it still work if the user manually enters a new value in the `attEdgeUpDown` control? If I go from 7 to 1 by manually typing it in, will it just hide/uncheck `attEdgeBox7` or all of them except `attEdgeBox1`?

Comment: No, this only works when you go up/down by 1, whether by using the arrow buttons or typing the value. I didn't know the user was allowed to enter a value manually. I'll provide an edit that allows this.

Comment: @FatMan see my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer LINQ you can greatly reduce the code. I am assuming that all checkboxes are hidded by default.

```
var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name);

foreach (var checkBox in checkBoxes)
{
    checkBox.Visible = false;
}

checkBoxes.Take(edgeValue).All(x => x.Visible = true);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this send unnecessary PropertyChanged events?